# How to embed libvlc player in Gtk3 window in Wayland

Tags: go, gtk3, libvlc

trying to write a simple media player in go. I'm using gotk3 and libvlc-go. The problem is my current method of embeding the player depends on X11. In wayland a new window is created for the player. This is my current code for calling the player taken from one of the examples.

```
func setPlayerWindow(player *vlc.Player, window *gdk.Window) error {
    return player.SetXWindow(window.GetXID())
}
```

...

```
    signals := map[string]interface{}{
        "onDrawRender": func(playerArea *gtk.DrawingArea, cr *cairo.Context) {
            cr.SetSourceRGB(0, 0, 0)
            cr.Paint()
        },
        "onRealizeRender": func(playerArea *gtk.DrawingArea) {
            playerWindow, err := playerArea.GetWindow()
            assertError(err)

            err = setPlayerWindow(player, playerWindow)
            if _, err := player.LoadMediaFromPath("video.mp4"); err != nil {
                log.Println("can't play file")
            }
            player.Play()
            player.SetPause(true)
        },
        "onTogglePlay": func() {
            _ = player.TogglePause()
        },
    }
```

As I said this works for X11 but not for Wayland. I also tried something similar in python, with MPV instead of VLC, and found a solution using OpenGL area; but I wasn't able to translate it to VLC.

How can achieve this in Wayland? Will it be compatible with X11 or will I need a separate implementation for each? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your app runs Wayland under X11, this should work. See the official GTK LibVLC sample here https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/doc/libvlc/gtk_player.c

```c
void player_widget_on_realize(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(media_player, GDK_WINDOW_XID(gtk_widget_get_window(widget)));
}
```

You should try and find the corresponding Go function for `gtk_widget_get_window` in the GTK Go binding you are using, and call it (`window.GetXID()` may be different).

If this does not work, your last option as of today is to [implement OpenGL callbacks](https://videolan.videolan.me/vlc/group__libvlc__media__player.html#gafae363ba4c4655780b0403e00159be56), available in the development version of LibVLC 4. This is a new low-level API to implement, and it is not quite stable yet.

Proper built-in Wayland support in LibVLC is planned and you can subscribe for updates at https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/16106.